# Wordpress4.1.15 Dashboard links not working

Tags: admin, links, dashboard

I have Wordpress 4.1.15. When I tried to update to ver. 4.7.2 (clicked the link on the dashboard). It wrked for few seconds and returned back to dashboard screen.
After that, no links in Dashboard are working anymore. List of plugins,pages, etc.
The link at the bottom of the page is displayed properly (e.g.wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page). If I click the link, it works for few seconds("waiting for response") and stops - left at Dashboard home page.
What can be a problem? How I can debug/fix it?
Thank you,
Leo

Comment: 4.1.15 to 4.7.2 is quite a jump. It would be best to upgrade a version at a time. It s less risky

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your upgrade hasn't worked properly. Does it still think you have an upgrade to 4.7.2 waiting?
Personally I would download a fresh copy of 4.7.2 and re-upload this to be sure nothing is broken or missing. Make sure to take a backup of your database and files should anything bad happen.

This may be helpful: https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_Extended

Comment: Yes, no update happened -it is the same version as before. It still displays that 4.7.2 update is available. I did not update manually yet.